# Create Confluence page using Python and Atlassian API

Tags: python, confluence-rest-api

I try to create a Confluence page with Python by:

```
from atlassian import Confluence  

def writeConfluencePage(confluenceBaseUrl,parentId,user,password):  

    # connect to Confluence
    confluence = Confluence(url=confluenceBaseUrl,username=user,password=password)
    
    # create page
    status = confluence.create_page(  
    space='TEST', 
    parent_id=parentId,
    title='Made by Python',  
    body='This is the body')
      
    print(status)
```

With this I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Could not create content with type page
```

The `parentId` definitely exists. The `space` not, but I think I have to create something, do I? I also have definitely write access to the parent page.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code of the function create_page:

```
data = {
    "type": type,
    "title": title,
    "space": {"key": space},
    "body": self._create_body(body, representation),
}
```

so in space you must specify the key, not the name

```
from atlassian import Confluence  

def writeConfluencePage(confluenceBaseUrl,parentId,user,password):  

    # connect to Confluence
    confluence = Confluence(url=confluenceBaseUrl,username=user,password=password)  
    
    # get space
    content = confluence.get_page_by_id(page_id=parentId)
    space = content["space"].get("key")

    # create page
    status = confluence.create_page(  
    space=space, 
    parent_id=parentId,
    title='Made by Python',  
    body='This is the body')
      
    print(status)
```